# How to add short description to a pytest so it's shown in the short summary report?

Tags: python, pytest

How to add short description to a pytest so it's shown in the short summary report? e.g. something like:

```
@pytest.short.desc("Just making sure we got Fibonacci right.")
def test_fib():
    assert fib(1) == 1
    assert fib(2) == 1
    assert fib(7) == 13
    with pytest.raises(AssertionError):
       fib(-10)
```

Would lead to the following output:

```
(PyRepo) /somewhere/somepath>pytest -rA
======================================= test session starts =======================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /somewhere/somepath/scripts/python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /somewhere/somepath, inifile: setup.cfg, testpaths: tests
plugins: cov-2.8.1
collected 1 item

tests/test_skeleton.py::test_fib PASSED                                                      [100%]

============================================= PASSES ==============================================

----------- coverage: platform win32, python 3.7.6-final-0 -----------
Name                       Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/myproject/skeleton.py      33     14      2      0    60%   56-81, 90-91, 101-105, 111

===================================== short test summary info =====================================
PASSED tests/test_skeleton.py::test_fib     Just making sure we got Fibonacci right. 
======================================== 1 passed in 0.26s ========================================
```

Comment: Why not just pick a descriptive test name?

Comment: @Voo right but what if you want to show an auto generated summary in a team meeting where not all are coders?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, but I would strongly recommend against doing that anyhow. It's the completely wrong level. The business doesn't care that you have "unit tests" and those technical details, they care about the product. 
And you can do a lot with expressive class and method names. You can use some very different naming conventions for those than in normal code. [Here's](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/blob/master/tests/NSubstitute.Acceptance.Specs/ReturningResults.cs) one example in C# that springs to mind.

Comment: @Voo you have a different philosophy and opinion, I respect that, would you then also respect mine to have a short user readable description ...?

Comment: Sure, just telling you why you won't find anything premade for that. You can build your own though by creating JUnitXml files and [recording properties](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files) and then formatting the results however you want.

Comment: @Voo that sounds like a good answer ... can you please provide a minimal answer and I will happily accept.